# Why scanf function do not accept escape sequences as an input?

Tags: c

Why scanf function do not accept escape sequences as an input?

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char str[100];

        printf("Enter value: ");
        scanf("%s", str);

        printf("\nYou Entered: %s", str);

}
```

**Output**

```
Enter value: hello \n world
You Entered: hello
```

Answer (score 3):

`%s` only reads in input up to the first whitespace character - in this case, the space. Thus, it only recognizes "hello", since the rest of the input has not been read.

That being said, `scanf` [can't interpret escaped characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3194616/7431860). You could put an *actual* newline in your input, but you can't use escaped characters and expect it to properly parse them.

[In C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51864254/7431860), if there's a `\n` in a string literal, it'll be printed as a newline (the compiler does that) but if there's a `\n` in your input it'll be interpreted literally.

Comment: Thanks for the answere...but what should i do to take \n as an input?

Comment: See updated answer - the long and short of it is, you can't. `scanf` doesn't process "\n" as a newline; you'd need to write logic into your program to replace `\n` with an actual newline.